# How do I configure a domain name using poweradmin

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ubuntu-11.10

I'm not sure if this is possible but I have a hunch it is.
I'm using a domain say abc.co.cc which points to namecheap name servers.

I'm hosting my website on my ubuntu 11.10 machine(laptop) and I have correctly managed to setup ddclient and dynamic dns service provided by namecheap. This is done by pointing a A record to my laptops IP address..

I have installed power dns as my preferred dns server and since I'm new to configuring a dns server I've installed power admin .. I followed the instructions from http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-powerdns-with-mysql-backend-and-poweradmin-on-debian-etch

I have set up a catch all domain from namecheap to point to abc.co.cc .. Now I want to manage all subdomain records on my laptop .. How do I do that ??

Comment: As this isn't _really_ programming related, you might have a better chance of getting this answered on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The domain/subdomain you are hosting needs to have your laptop as the DNS server. This is done using NS records.

I don't think dyndns allows you to update NS records.